# Build Wix installer Project in Teamcity 9.1, but how to set the `WixToolPath` in build machine?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, teamcity

I'm using Win10 64bit OS, with Wix3.11RC Toolset installed. My VS2017 have created a Wix v3 installer Project. Our team is using TeamCity9.1 as the CI tool.

Now I want to make the Build Agent in TeamCity to support `wixproj` build without touch CI server settings(I **don't have privilege** ).  I basically follow some tutorials to checked in all necessary Wix build files(the wix `Bin` folder, and the `wix.targets` ) which is put in a relative path to the source code, now I'm blocked with the path issue in editing `.wixproj` file, the official doc said:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <WixToolPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\</WixToolPath>
      <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
      <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And this is mine:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <WixToolPath>..\..\wix\3.11\</WixToolPath>
      <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)targetsFile\v3.x\wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
      <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The reason I'm using the relative path for `WixToolPath` is the `$(SourceCodeControlRoot)` was resolved as `D:\` here, but actually the source code will be checked out by CI server and put under a random folder like `D:\ABC\f14c7929aa63f1fc`. By my configuration, the local build even can't go through, the build error indicates the `WixTasksPath` had been resolved to a non-existed path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\..\..\wix\3.11\wixtasks.dll`

So how can I achieve? thanks!

Comment: This issue has been marked as documentation bug on the GitHub: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/1911. unfortunately, there is no any update about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches you can try is to change the path in the file to the absolute path using TeamCity-provided references before invoking the tool. In TeamCity settings you can reference the checkout directory path as %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir% or use ${teamcity.build.checkoutDir} within MSBuild step if run as MSBuild build step.
You can do the replacement in the first build step or just use TeamCity [file content replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer) to change the old value to new one.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<WixTasksPath>wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
```

this worked for me.